# Can't understand why XCode linker doesn't see certain methods

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I've just picked up C++ after years of meaning to. Right now I'm trying to implement a simple matrix class to be used from other classes. Following [GManNickG's lead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076670/182048), here's my `SimpleMatrix` (declared in "SimpleMatrix.h"):

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class SimpleMatrix {    
    unsigned int numCols, numRows;    
public:    
    std::vector<T> data;

    SimpleMatrix(unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows) :
    numCols(cols),
    numRows(rows),
    data(numCols * numRows)
    {};

    T getElement(unsigned int column, unsigned int row);
    void setShape(unsigned int column, unsigned int row, const T& initValue);    
};
```

and implemented as (in "SimpleMatrix.cpp"):

```
#include "SimpleMatrix.h"

template <class T>
T SimpleMatrix<T>::getElement(unsigned int column, unsigned int row) {   
    return data[row * numCols - 1];    
}

template <class T>
void SimpleMatrix<T>::setShape(unsigned int columns, unsigned int rows, const T& initValue) {
    numCols = columns;
    numRows = rows;
    data.assign(columns * rows, initValue);
}
```

Now, when I use `SimpleMatrix` from `main`, it compiles, links and works fine. When I try to use it from an object `Container` declared as (in "Container.h"):

```
#include "SimpleMatrix.h"

class Container {
public:    
    SimpleMatrix<int> matrix;    
    Container();    
    void doStuff();
};
```

and implemented as (in "Container.cpp"):

```
#include "Container.h"
#include "SimpleMatrix.h"

void Container::doStuff() {    
    this->matrix.setShape(2, 2, 0);
    this->matrix.getElement(1, 1);
}
```

Xcode complains that

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> ```
> "SimpleMatrix<int>::getElement(unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
> Container::doStuff() in Container.o   
>
> "SimpleMatrix<int>::setShape(unsigned int, unsigned int, int const&)", referenced from:
> Container::doStuff() in Container.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've checked the "Build Phases/Compile Sources"-settings, and all three files are there (main.cpp, SimpleMatrix.cpp, and Container.cpp).

There are probably a number of issues with this code. One that springs to mind is the lack of a default constructor for `SimpleMatrix`, but that's not really what concerns me here. I just can't understand what the fundamental difference between the two cases is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of templates has to be in the header file.